# In Through One Hole

Tags: riddle

You go in through one hole, you come out three holes.

Once you’re inside you’re ready to go outside, but once you're outside you’re still inside.

What is it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My answer:

> **A shirt**. The shirt has three holes: two sleeves and one neck. Once you're wearing the shirt, you're ready to go outside, but once you're outside, you're still wearing the shirt.

Answer (score -3):

I think it is....

> pants. there is one hole for your waist and two for your feet. when you put them on, you are ready to go outside, but once outside, you will still (hopefully) be wearing your pants

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange.  (1) This is a rather blatant rip-off of the accepted answer.  (2) It seems to be that, in your answer, you go in through one hole and you come out ***two*** holes.  (3) I guess it's not critical for a question over 1⅓ years old, but please get into the habit of using spoiler markdown in answers.

Answer (score -3):

I believe it is

> shirt....as it has two holes for the sleeve and one hole for the head...then you go out but you stay in your clothing.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This question was already answered over a year ago - please look at other answers before posting your own.